# How to run JavaScript in Android WebView if the device doesn't have browser?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I build an android app in EDC, and in that, device doesn't have a browser. How to run JavaScript in Android WebView if the device doesn't have browser? This is my code and everything that I've already tried.

```
private fun webView(url: String) {

        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        binding.webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        binding.webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        binding.webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        binding.webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        binding.webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        binding.webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
        binding.webView.settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        binding.webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        binding.webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        binding.webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        binding.webView.requestFocusFromTouch()
        binding.webView.settings.displayZoomControls = false
        binding.webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        binding.webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
        binding.webView.settings.defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
        binding.webView.clearCache(true)
        binding.webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
        binding.webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        binding.webView.settings.blockNetworkImage = false
        binding.webView.settings.blockNetworkLoads = false
        binding.webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
        binding.webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = true
        binding.webView.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        binding.webView.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)

        // Clear cookies to avoid potential issues with session information
        val cookieManager: CookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
        cookieManager.removeAllCookies(null)

        binding.webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

            override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest) {
                Log.d("onPermissionReq", "permission granted")
                    request.grant(request.resources)
            }

            @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            override fun onJsAlert(
                    view: WebView?,
                    url: String?,
                    message: String?,
                    result: JsResult?
            ): Boolean {
                Log.d("cekJsAlert", "on js alert")
                return true
            }

            override fun onJsPrompt(view: WebView?, url: String?, message: String?, defaultValue: String?, result: JsPromptResult?): Boolean {
                Log.d("cekJsAlert", "on js prompt")
                return true
            }

            override fun onJsConfirm(view: WebView?, url: String?, message: String?, result: JsResult?): Boolean {
                Log.d("cekJsAlert", "on js confirm")
                return true
            }

            override fun onJsBeforeUnload(view: WebView?, url: String?, message: String?, result: JsResult?): Boolean {
                Log.d("cekJsAlert", "on js before load")
                return true
            }

            override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage?): Boolean {
                consoleMessage?.message()?.let { Log.d("WebViewConsole", it) }
                return true
            }
        }


        binding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressLint("WebViewClientOnReceivedSslError")
            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java", ReplaceWith("handler?.proceed()"))

            override fun onReceivedSslError(
                    view: WebView?,
                    handler: SslErrorHandler?,
                    error: android.net.http.SslError?
            ) {
                // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                handler?.proceed()
            }

            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                if (url != null) {
                    view?.loadUrl(url)
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                Log.d("WebView", "Page started loading: $url")
                binding.loading.progressbarLoading.visibility = VISIBLE
                CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
                CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view!!, true)
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                Log.d("WebView", "Page finished loading: $url")
                binding.loading.progressbarLoading.visibility = GONE
            }

            override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url)
            }

            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
            }

            override fun onRenderProcessGone(view: WebView?, detail: RenderProcessGoneDetail?): Boolean {
                return super.onRenderProcessGone(view, detail)
            }

        }

        binding.webView.loadUrl(url)
    }
```

I want to use WebView and run the JavaScript too (I can already load the webpage but everything that related with JavaScript is not working like JavaScript alert, sweetalert2, etc.)

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with not having a browser? FireFox? Opera?

Comment: because I tried the code with the emulator that have a browser and its works fine. but in another device that doesn't have a browser it didn't work

Comment: I think the device has yet other apps installed that the emulator does not have. And vice-versa. Why dont you blame one of these apps?

Comment: If you would say: its missing Chrome... Instead of just a browser..

Comment: Instal Chrome on that device. If only for a test.

Comment: Try another device where Chrome installed.

Comment: If Android has a browser or not is not relevant for the WebView. A browser like Chrome can be used as WebView provider (see developer options) but usually on recent devices Google uses a dedicated WebView app that acts as WebView provider. If your device doesn't have Chrome or a WebView provider app installed you have to install the WebView provider or you can not use WebViews.

Comment: I can already use a WebView but that's not work properly, my WebView just display the HTML CSS but for the JavaScript like JsAlert, SweetAlert2 on the website is not working in my WebView.

and then I try on another device that has a browser/Chrome. and all the features on the website is work properly, that makes me think that's all because my device is does not have a browser or Chrome.

So, I just want to ask is it possible for me to get all the feature from the website in my WebView?